# H2 MERGE INTO ... USING with multiple values, do NOT update if exists

Tags: sql, spring-boot, h2

I am currently writing a **data.sql** SQL-script for my spring-boot application. I want it to fill in default values for various tables (e.g. on initial start-up).

I have set `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update` in the *application.properties* to keep the contents of the database, but the data.sql is executed each time the service boots up.

Now I am looking for a way to **insert rows** if they do not exist **without updating them if they do exist**.

I am using **H2Dialect** (and a H2-database).

Initially I wanted to use some sort of "`IF NOT EXISTS`"-statement along with `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table`, but it seems H2 does not support this directly.

So the **next best thing** to do is to use `MERGE INTO`, but this does not seem to work as expected and I do not understand why so.

This is what my script looks like, but sadly it does not work as expected:

```
MERGE INTO Languages AS T USING (SELECT * FROM Languages) AS S ON (T.ID = S.ID)
    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
        INSERT (LANGUAGE_CODE, NAME, I18N_NAME, LOCALIZE_UI, CAN_CHOOSE) VALUES
        ('en', 'English', 'USA', TRUE, TRUE),
        ('de', 'German', 'Deutschland', FALSE, FALSE);
```

I'd like to add these values **either if they are absent** (which is probably easier) **or if there are no values present in the Languages-table** (which is what I would prefer).

This is the (shortened) exception I receive when I start my spring-boot application:

```
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Syntax Fehler in SQL Befehl "MERGE INTO LANGUAGES AS[*] T USING (SELECT * FROM LANGUAGES) AS S ON (T.ID = S.ID) WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT (LANGUAGE_CODE, NAME, I18N_NAME, LOCALIZE_UI, CAN_CHOOSE) VALUES ('en', 'English', 'USA', TRUE, TRUE), ('de', 'German', 'Deutschland', FALSE, FALSE) "; erwartet "., (, KEY, VALUES, (, WITH, SELECT, FROM"
Syntax error in SQL statement "MERGE INTO LANGUAGES AS[*] T USING (SELECT * FROM LANGUAGES) AS S ON (T.ID = S.ID) WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT (LANGUAGE_CODE, NAME, I18N_NAME, LOCALIZE_UI, CAN_CHOOSE) VALUES ('en', 'English', 'USA', TRUE, TRUE), ('de', 'German', 'Deutschland', FALSE, FALSE) "; expected "., (, KEY, VALUES, (, WITH, SELECT, FROM"; SQL statement:
MERGE INTO Languages AS T USING (SELECT * FROM Languages) AS S ON (T.ID = S.ID) WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT (LANGUAGE_CODE, NAME, I18N_NAME, LOCALIZE_UI, CAN_CHOOSE) VALUES ('en', 'English', 'USA', TRUE, TRUE), ('de', 'German', 'Deutschland', FALSE, FALSE) [42001-196]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:345) ~[h2-1.4.196.jar:1.4.196]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getSyntaxError(DbException.java:205) ~[h2-1.4.196.jar:1.4.196]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.getSyntaxError(Parser.java:541) ~[h2-1.4.196.jar:1.4.196]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parseSelectSimple(Parser.java:2073) ~[h2-1.4.196.jar:1.4.196]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parseSelectSub(Parser.java:1940) ~[h2-1.4.196.jar:1.4.196]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parseSelectUnion(Parser.java:1755) ~[h2-1.4.196.jar:1.4.196]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parseSelect(Parser.java:1743) ~[h2-1.4.196.jar:1.4.196]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parseMerge(Parser.java:1053) ~[h2-1.4.196.jar:1.4.196]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parsePrepared(Parser.java:423) ~[h2-1.4.196.jar:1.4.196]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parse(Parser.java:321) ~[h2-1.4.196.jar:1.4.196]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parse(Parser.java:297) ~[h2-1.4.196.jar:1.4.196]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.prepareCommand(Parser.java:258) ~[h2-1.4.196.jar:1.4.196]
    at org.h2.engine.Session.prepareLocal(Session.java:578) ~[h2-1.4.196.jar:1.4.196]
    at org.h2.engine.Session.prepareCommand(Session.java:519) ~[h2-1.4.196.jar:1.4.196]
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.prepareCommand(JdbcConnection.java:1204) ~[h2-1.4.196.jar:1.4.196]
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcStatement.executeInternal(JdbcStatement.java:176) ~[h2-1.4.196.jar:1.4.196]
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcStatement.execute(JdbcStatement.java:164) ~[h2-1.4.196.jar:1.4.196]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.StatementFacade$StatementProxy.invoke(StatementFacade.java:114) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.5.27.jar:na]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy97.execute(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptUtils.executeSqlScript(ScriptUtils.java:470) ~[spring-jdbc-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    ... 78 common frames omitted
```

The exception stacktrace is huge, but the "caused by"-parts basically say, that beans could not be created due to the deepest exception, the "caused by"-clause of which I posted above. If anyone needs more details, please let me know.

**Edit:** or is there a **best practice for initializing data** (such as default user or default anything)? Preferably one I can reuse if a database reset is performed.

---

**Edit (25.04.2018):** I figured something might have gone wrong with my Language-class, because the SQL for schema creation looks a little odd. Here it is:

```
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation.JsonDeserialize;
import com.particles.authservice.jwtservice.JSONHelper;
import com.particles.authservice.languageservice.converters.LanguageDeserializer;

import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

/**
 * This class describes the entity for a language.
 */
@JsonDeserialize(using = LanguageDeserializer.class)
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity(name = "Languages")
public class Language {
    private static Language defaultLanguage;

    @Id
    @Column(nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String  languageCode;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String  name;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String  i18nName;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private boolean localizeUi = false;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private boolean canChoose  = false;

    /**
     * This method sets the class attribute {@link Language#defaultLanguage}.
     * 
     * @param defaultLanguage
     *            ({@link Language}) default language
     */
    public static void setDefaultLanguage(final Language defaultLanguage) {
        Language.defaultLanguage = defaultLanguage;
    }

    /**
     * @return ({@link Language}) default language
     */
    public static Language getDefaultLanguage() {
        return Language.defaultLanguage;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Now I am looking for a way to insert rows if they do not exist without updating them if they do exist.

You could use `INSERT INTO ... SELECT ...`:

```
INSERT INTO Languages(LANGUAGE_CODE, NAME, I18N_NAME, LOCALIZE_UI, CAN_CHOOSE) 
SELECT LANGUAGE_CODE, NAME, I18N_NAME, LOCALIZE_UI, CAN_CHOOSE
FROM (SELECT 'en' AS Language_code, 'English' AS name,
      'USA' AS I18N_NAME, TRUE AS LOCALIZE_UI, TRUE AS CAN_CHOOSE
      UNION ALL
      SELECT 'de', 'German', 'Deutschland', FALSE, FALSE
      ) sub
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM Languages l
                  WHERE sub.Language_code = l.Language_code);
```

Assuming that `LANGUAGE_CODE` is UNIQUE, otherwise you need to explicitly specify `ID` column.

---

Alternatively using `MINUS/EXCEPT`:

```
INSERT INTO Languages(LANGUAGE_CODE, NAME, I18N_NAME, LOCALIZE_UI, CAN_CHOOSE) 
SELECT LANGUAGE_CODE, NAME, I18N_NAME, LOCALIZE_UI, CAN_CHOOSE
FROM (SELECT 'en' AS Language_code, 'English' AS name,
      'USA' AS I18N_NAME, TRUE AS LOCALIZE_UI, TRUE AS CAN_CHOOSE
      UNION ALL
      SELECT 'de', 'German', 'Deutschland', FALSE, FALSE
      ) sub
EXCEPT
SELECT LANGUAGE_CODE, NAME, I18N_NAME, LOCALIZE_UI, CAN_CHOOSE
FROM Languages;
```

---

**EDIT:**

> *Is there for instance a way to avoid UNION?*

I am not sure if H2 supports `VALUES` clause:

```
SELECT LANGUAGE_CODE, NAME, I18N_NAME, LOCALIZE_UI, CAN_CHOOSE
FROM (SELECT 'en' AS Language_code, 'English' AS name,
      'USA' AS I18N_NAME, TRUE AS LOCALIZE_UI, TRUE AS CAN_CHOOSE
      UNION ALL
      SELECT 'de', 'German', 'Deutschland', FALSE, FALSE
      ) sub

<=>

SELECT *
FROM (VALUES('en', 'English', 'USA', TRUE, TRUE),
             ('de', 'German', 'Deutschland', FALSE, FALSE)
     ) sub(LANGUAGE_CODE, NAME, I18N_NAME, LOCALIZE_UI, CAN_CHOOSE)
```

**[SQLFiddle Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=8c1de1a5aeba8dbf797bd7288464ea8c)**

Comment: Thank you for your reply as well! I prefer the answer from @Pankaj_Gadge, because it looks more elegant and straight-forward, but your statements seem to work (and return the proper amount of rows updated (if any)). Still: I cannot entirely understand how it works - in particular I do not understand how you specify the target table (`Languages`) along with a select / sub-select(s). Is there for instance a way to avoid UNION?

Comment: thanks again! Indeed! It seems H2 understands `VALUES` in `SELECT ... FROM ...`, but it does not seem to properly understand the thing you specified after sub in brackets. Instead it delivers values C1 till Cx (in my case C5) and once I map it (by using `SELECT C1 AS LANGUAGE_CODE, C2 AS ...`) I have to wrap it into yet another `SELECT *`. Then it works as expected (it seems it works in H2, but not on Postgres or MySQL, but that's okay for me). Here's a sample for the whole INSERT-call: https://pastebin.com/DaZA7AYy

Answer (score 1):

Based on your requirements, you should be able to use [MERGE](http://www.h2database.com/html/grammar.html#merge) statement without using `WHEN NOT MATCHED` clause.

> **MERGE**:
>
> Updates existing rows, and insert rows that don't exist. If no key
>   column is specified, the primary key columns are used to find the row.
>   If more than one row per new row is affected, an exception is thrown.

```
MERGE INTO Languages 
KEY(LANGUAGE_CODE, NAME, I18N_NAME, LOCALIZE_UI, CAN_CHOOSE) VALUES
('en', 'English', 'USA', TRUE, TRUE),
('de', 'German', 'Deutschland', FALSE, FALSE);
```

Let me know if this still doesn't work for you.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! **It works** - but only if I **re-order the columns in "KEY"** (and the values) to the natural order the table has been created with by hibernate (which in my case is: LANGUAGE_CODE, CAN_CHOOSE, I18N_NAME, LOCALIZE_UI, NAME). It seems as if KEY order is ignored. **Do you happen to have an idea of why the order in KEY is not used?** (The error I receive if I copy&paste your suggestion is: `Data conversion error converting "'English' (LANGUAGES: CAN_CHOOSE BOOLEAN NOT NULL)"; SQL statement: ... [22018-196]`).

Comment: I added my `Language`-class to the question above. I suspect, that the table created from this class might contain an error.